# What is the technology behind streaming pages like earthcam.com?

Tags: node.js, flash, web-applications, video-streaming

There are some webpages that stream the live video to the browser, let's take an example of www.earthcam.com - does anyone know how exactly does it work?
Do they have the stream sent through some node.js server with some protocols (what kind of?), etc. As I understand there are only few formats supported on each platform:

```
Safari:

HLS (iOS and mac only)
h.264
MP4
Firefox

DASH (via MSE but no h.264)
h.264 via Flash only!
VP9
MP4
OGG
Webm
IE

Flash
DASH (via MSE IE 11+ only)
h.264
MP4
Chrome

Flash
DASH (via MSE)
h.264
VP9
MP4
webm
ogg
```

And earth cam works everywhere. Do they use flash in case of windows and some other technology in case of Mac OS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they detect what browser you are using (User-Agent), and choose a technology that works for that platform.